# Getting started using C# and Physics (Resources, Tutorials, Samples, etc.)

Tags: c#, physics

As an application developer, I plan on now getting started in game development so I have come along to this site.

I am a proficient C# developer so I guess it makes sense to start game development in the same language, unless someone directs me otherwise.

I'm looking for some "getting started" type of tutorials that cover basic game architecture and essential physics such as collision, velocity, gravity, friction etc.

I know about XNA and physics engines such as farseer but, at the moment, I'd like to get started without attaching myself to a particular framework or set of classes.

Please let me know of good resource, tutorials, etc. that will get me started in this manner.

Comment: You should really start with XNA and probably don't even bother with physics in the beggining. And if you start with XNA then -> create.msdn.com

Comment: @Kikaimaru Thanks, but I am interested in the physics and I don't want to use XNA at this time.

Comment: You'll need to use *some* API for rendering, otherwise you won't be seeing the effects of your physics simulation. You say you are proficient in C#, but do you have any experience with *graphics* in C#? It could be for instance, just plain old GDI in WinForms, a DirectX wrapper like SlimDX or SharpDX, an OpenGL wrapper like OpenTK, or a game-oriented framework like XNA. Doesn't really matter which, but you'll need to learn at least one graphics API, otherwise how do you expect to see your physics running?

Comment: @DavidGouveia Thanks.  I have minimal GDI experience.  Would you suggest using a DirectX wrapper.  I guess I'm trying to avoid using too large a framework that will do too much for me.

Comment: Then the suggestion to use XNA is quite valid. Take a [look at this](http://pastie.org/3853441). This is the amount of code you need to add to an empty XNA project to get it to render a sprite. And that's pretty much the extent of what you'd need to learn from the framework in order to to play around with physics. In comparison, it's a lot less work than any of the alternatives I mentioned.

Comment: @DavidGouveia Thanks for that.  Perhaps, I have had the misconception about XNA that it "does it all for you".  I guess I will go with XNA.  Thanks Kikaimaru also.  David, if you would like to combine your comments into an answer I will accept and upvote.

Comment: XNA does not really work at that much of a higher level than DirectX or OpenGL. It's just that it comes with a lot of additional classes and abstractions that are very useful for game programming, whereas DirectX and OpenGL are more general.

Comment: By the way, if your plan is to make a game (even physics based game) then do NOT create your own physics engine, just use existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know about XNA and physics engines such as farseer but, at the moment, I'd like to get started without attaching myself to a particular framework or set of classes.

You'll need to use some API for rendering, otherwise you won't be seeing the effects of your physics simulation. You say you are proficient in C#, but do you have any experience with graphics in C#? It could be for instance, just plain old GDI in WinForms, a DirectX wrapper like SlimDX or SharpDX, an OpenGL wrapper like OpenTK, or a game-oriented framework like XNA. Doesn't really matter which, but you'll need to learn at least one graphics API, otherwise how do you expect to see your physics running?

> I guess I'm trying to avoid using too large a framework that will do too much for me.

Then the suggestion to use XNA is quite valid. Take a look at [this](http://pastie.org/3853441). This is the amount of code you need to add to an empty XNA project to get it to render a sprite. And that's pretty much the extent of what you'd need to learn from the framework in order to to play around with physics. In comparison, it's a lot less work than any of the alternatives I mentioned.

So if your intent is just to get your hands dirty with physics, I'd recommend learning the bare minimum required to do some rendering in XNA; and then try and play around with [Velcro Physics](https://github.com/Genbox/VelcroPhysics) (formerly Farseer Physics) for instance. Shouldn't be hard to find some tutorials by googling.

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks, David.  Hopefully I'll be back soon with some sensible questions.